# javascript calling DataSnap REST makes browser unresponsive

Tags: javascript, rest, delphi, delphi-xe7, datasnap

I use Delphi XE7. When my Javascript calls my server function that need around 800ms to read sensor and return data, The browser is unresponsive from the moment I click the button to invoke the Javascript until it finally response returns. I'm using the default Javascript generated by the proxy var `serverMethods().getChannel(i);` to call into my server function.

Javascript call look like this:

```
var s = serverMethods().getChannel(i);
      serial[i].$sensorlValue.text(s.result.fields.sensorString);
      serial[i].$sensorlRealValue.text(s.result.fields.sensor);
      serial[i].$sensorStatus.text(s.result.fields.sensorStatus+' '+s.result.fields.name);
      serial[i].$sensorError.text(s.result.fields.sensorError);
      serial[i].$AVString.text(s.result.fields.AVString);
      serial[i].$AVError.text(s.result.fields.AVError);
```

So by default example there are no Javascript callbacks or promise, so embaracaderom manage somehow to block Javascript from executing until response is back and variable a receive values?

I think about try using jQuery Ajax call on URL, but is there any other solution?

Because serverMethods are generated from proxy but for $ajax I need to manually set each of them. Or maybe I do something wrong here and serverMethods can be used without blocking ?

Thanks.

Comment: Dont be a smartass, i know this is browser side JS problem, and it has everithing with delphi server because it generate that client side JS, and it generate it with example that work like this, so It has everithing with delphi, because thay give this code from thay proxygenerator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem after researching execution path in ServerFunctionExecutor.js that is called on serverMethods().SOMEAPIFUNCTION()
1. Help and documentation are 0, and google + XE7 questions are 0. So if someone from embaracadero read this PLS MAKE DECENT DOCUMENTATION.

ServerFunctionExecutor.js had on line 263

```
   //async is only true if there is a callback that can be notified on completion
var useCallback = (callback != null);
request.open(requestType, url, useCallback);

if (useCallback)
{
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4)
    {
      //the callback will be notified the execution finished even if there is no expected result
      JSONResult = hasResult ? parseHTTPResponse(request) : null;
      callback(JSONResult, request.status, owner);
    }
  };
}
```

So it is posible and NOT DOCUMENTED to use callback for unblocking GUI.
Use it as:

```
serverMethods().SOMEAPIFUNCTION(par1,par2,.... callback)
```

If you have Server method defined in delphi code with for example 3 parameters in js 4th parameter is callback:

For this example code now look like this:

```
 serverMethods().getChannel(i,function(a,b,c){
            serial.$sensorlValue.text(a.result[0].fields.sensorString);
            serial.$sensorlRealValue.text(a.result[0].fields.sensor);
            serial.$sensorStatus.text(a.result[0].fields.sensorStatus+' '+s.result.fields.name);
            serial[i].$sensorError.text(a.result[0].fields.sensorError);
            serial[i].$AVString.text(a.result[0].fields.AVString);
            serial[i].$AVError.text(a.result[0].fields.AVError);
          });
```

a is JSON reponse
b is Request status as number 200 or somethin else
c is owner usuali undefined